# Connect Respberry 3 to VGA monitor using HDMI to VGA Converter

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I have 2 devices Device A and B and a LCD monitor M with VGA port.

- Device A : Laptop Sony Vaio(HDMI output)
- Device B : Respberrypi 3 (HDMI output)
- Device S : Satellite dish TV Setup box(HDMI output).
- Device M: LCD Monitor VGA port (input).
- Device X : Some other LCD Monitor with HDMI port (input).

**What I want to do?**

**Connect Device B(using HDMI to VGA converter) to Device M.**

***Following test cases I have performed :***

- Device A -> HDMI to VGA converter -> M (works fine).

This means Device A, HDMI to VGA converter and Monitor M are working fine.

- Device B-> HDMI cable -> X (works fine).

This means Device B is working.

This ***means Device A,B , Monitor M, HDMI to VGA converter all are working fine***.

But,

**Device B -> HDMI to VGA converter -> M (not working, LCD showing no signal found).**

**Device S -> HDMI to VGA converter -> M (not working, LCD showing no signal found).**

Where is the problem while connecting Device B to monitor M?
Thanks..!

Comment: Maybe try http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com?